# PHP, Not able to send Emails

Tags: php, forms, validation

I would like to have a contact form on my that requires the *fullname, *email address, and *subject and *message. I followed a tutorial to develop my form but for some reason it is not sending my test message.

I'm not experienced enough with PHP to figure out what I am doing wrong, so I am hoping to get suggestions on how to resolve this issue. All questions, suggestions, and possible solutions are welcome. Thanks.

contact form php:
Code:

```
<?php 

// EDIT THE FOLLOWING LINE BELOW AS REQUIRED

$send_email_to = "jb@me.com";

function send_email($name,$email,$email_subject,$email_message)
{
  global $send_email_to;  

  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: ".$email. "\r\n";

  $message = "<strong>Email = </strong>".$email."<br>";
  $message .= "<strong>Name = </strong>".$name."<br>";
  $message .= "<strong>Message = </strong>".$email_message."<br>";
  @mail($send_email_to, $email_subject, $message,$headers);
  return true;
}

function validate($name,$email,$message,$subject)
{
  $return_array = array();
  $return_array['success'] = '1';
  $return_array['name_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['email_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['message_msg'] = '';
  $return_array['subject'] = '';

 if($email == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['email_msg'] = 'email is required';
  }
  else
  {
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
      $return_array['email_msg'] = 'enter valid email.';  
    }
  }

  if($name == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['name_msg'] = 'name is required';
  }
  else
  {
     $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
    if (!preg_match($string_exp, $name)) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
     $return_array['name_msg'] = 'enter valid name.';
    }
  }


  if($subject == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['subject_msg'] = 'subject is required';
  }

  if($message == '')
  {
    $return_array['success'] = '0';
    $return_array['message_msg'] = 'message is required';
  }
  else
  {
    if (strlen($message) < 2) {
      $return_array['success'] = '0';
      $return_array['message_msg'] = 'enter valid message.';
    }
  }
  return $return_array;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$return_array = validate($name,$email,$message,$subject);
if($return_array['success'] == '1')
{
  send_email($name,$email,$subject,$message);
}

header('Content-type: text/json');
echo json_encode($return_array);
die();

?>
```

Contact Form HTML:
Code:

```
<fieldset id="contact_form">
          <div id="msgs"> </div>
          <form id="cform" name="cform" method="post" action="">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="Full Name*" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Full Name*') this.value = ''"
                            onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Full Name*'" />
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Email Address*" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email Address*') this.value = ''"
                            onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Email Address*'" />
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" value="Subject*" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Subject*') this.value = ''"
                            onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Subject*'" />
            <textarea id="msg" name="msg" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Your Message*') this.value = ''"
                            onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Your Message*'">Your Message*</textarea>
            <button id="submit" class="button"> Send Message</button>
          </form>
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: remove the "@" from mail ... and don't validate the email address by 'hand'

Comment: @Dagon: I'm guessing from the comment line that OP got that from somewhere, so it presumably works to some degree. Whether it works well though...

Comment: I agree with @Dagon. var_dump($_POST) to see if your form is reaching the controller.

Comment: the name validation is wrong also. just pre-empting the next post from the OP.

Comment: Judging by the json_encode() being used, I assume that AJAX is involved here. OP, you should be validating forms on the client-side as long as you are using JS. Get yourself jQuery if you aren't using it already, and then this plugin. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions. I was unable to follow a few of you suggestions being that i am not very experienced with PHP. I have tried applying action="contact.php" and removing @ from mail but unfortunately the form is still not sending.

Answer (score 0):

Your form's action isn't set to anything. You'll need to point it at the script you have there that sends the email.

Ie:

```
<form id.. name.. method.. action="/handle_post.php">
```

Comment: This is not the case at all. If you look at the script, it is posting to itself at the same url. action='' is a valid way of doing that (not that I would recommend it).

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte: Assuming that the form is being output by the same script, sure. However, judging from the fact that the script looks 'out-of-the-box', It's probably fine.

Comment: The PHP form script is still not working. I went back to the websites where i downloaded the script and it doesn't even work on there!!! So it looks like I will have to write a PHP form script.. *sigh*. Can anyone point me to a good tutorial on creating a php form script with validation? Also out of curiosity doesn't a php form have to be within a .php file or can it be in .html file?

Answer (score 0):

Set the correct action and then try it should work.. 
if it still does not work test it with curl utility to see if ur script is fine..
One more mistake that i saw was that ur text area form name is msg while on server ur expecting ur post request it have message. That wont work..
If u still face problem then we wd debug further :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set action to some script that will handle `$_POST` inputs (`contactform.php`) or `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` for the same file.

Second you should send data by input `type=submit` not button.

Comment: Leaving an empty string for the action attribute is a valid way to post a form to itself. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is unnecessary.